# appending to ORC file

Tags: hadoop, hive, orc

I'm new to Big data and related technologies, so I'm unsure if we can append data to the existing ORC file. I'm writing the ORC file using [Java API](https://github.com/apache/orc) and when I close the Writer, I'm unable to open the file again to write new content to it, basically to append new data.

Is there a way I can append data to the existing ORC file, either using Java Api or Hive or any other means?

One more clarification, when saving Java `util.Date` object into ORC file, ORC type is stored as:

```
struct<timestamp:struct<fasttime:bigint,cdate:struct<cachedyear:int,cachedfixeddatejan1:bigint,cachedfixeddatenextjan1:bigint>>,
```

and for java BigDecimal it's:

```
<margin:struct<intval:struct<signum:int,mag:struct<>,bitcount:int,bitlength:int,lowestsetbit:int,firstnonzerointnum:int>
```

Are these correct and is there  any info on this?

Comment: We can't help you if you don't post your code

Comment: Thanks for response, but I'm asking in general. does ORC files support append operation. i couldn't find related info anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot append directly to an ORC file. Nor to a Parquet file. Nor to any columnar format with a complex internal structure with metadata interleaved with data.

Quoting the official "[Apache Parquet](http://parquet.apache.org/documentation/latest/)" site...

> Metadata is written after the data to allow for **single pass writing**.

Then quoting the official "[Apache ORC](https://orc.apache.org/docs/file-tail.html)" site...

> Since **HDFS does not support changing the data in a file after it is
>   written**, ORC stores the top level index at the end of the file *(...)*
>   The file’s tail consists of 3 parts; the file metadata, file footer
>   and postscript.

Well, technically, nowadays you *can* append to an HDFS file; you can even truncate it. But these tricks are only useful for some edge cases (e.g. Flume feeding messages into an HDFS "log file", micro-batch-wise, with `fflush` from time to time).

For Hive transaction support they use a different trick: creating a new ORC file on each transaction (i.e. micro-batch) with periodic compaction jobs running in the background, *à la* HBase.

Answer (score 3):

**Update 2017**

Yes now you can! Hive provides a new support for [ACID](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Transactions#HiveTransactions-ConfigurationValuestoSetforINSERT,UPDATE,DELETE), but you can append data to your table using Append Mode `mode("append")` with [Spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SaveMode.html#Append)

Below an example

```
Seq((10, 20)).toDF("a", "b").write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("tab1")
Seq((20, 30)).toDF("a", "b").write.mode("append").saveAsTable("tab1")
sql("select * from tab1").show
```

Or a more complete exmple with ORC [here](http://jugsi.blogspot.com/2017/12/append-data-with-spark-to-hive-oarquet.html); below an extract:

```
val command = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url" .... ).load()
command.write.mode("append").format("orc").option("orc.compression","gzip").save("command.orc")
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible through Hive in which you can basically 'concatenate' newer data. From hive official documentation https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Transactions#HiveTransactions-WhatisACIDandwhyshouldyouuseit?

Comment: if i understand properly, it does the merging of multiple files, but what i am looking is option to add data to existing file without creating new file and merging it.